# How to use python functions in sql select statement

Tags: python, sql-server

I have one function(token_sort_ratio()) in python which compares two strings and gives the output as percentage match between them. I want to use that function in sql query which i'm running in python using pyodbc. But i cannot achieve it. Can anyone help me doing that.? 
Here is my code

```
cursor = conn.cursor() 
sql_query ="""select """+fuzz.token_sort_ratio("""[MAT DESC],MAT_GROUP_DESC""")+""" as percentage_match ,[MAT DESC] MAT_GROUP_DESC from Sample_data """  
cursor.execute(sql_query)  
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense at all. How could it possibly work?

Comment: Is there any work around to use python user defined function on columns of a table?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can either read back all the records from the database and work on them in Python or you can write your percentage match in SQL from the start. I would recommend rewriting it in SQL as it will be more efficient. You cannot ask SQL to run your Python commands.

Comment: Rob, What can be the best way to read all records in python and apply that function? I'm new to python I don't know much about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You can't even through IronPython compiled into DLL Assembly and such tricks. Your best bet is to rewrite it into T-SQL or - maybe a bit easier stuff - into one of the .NET languages and load them through .dll to SQL Server. I think the F# is perhaps most similar to Python but on the other hand the documentation on writing .dll for SQL Server is mostly for C#/VB.net so consider writing more complex stuff in C#